# I put solidify to one layer and thickess are different depends on area

Tags: solidify-modifier

I have aplied one solidify modifier to give thickness to one layer. but strangely one area has thicker solidify effect and other area very thin even though it's in same object.
[image]
Souldn't be thickness all the edge?
Does someone know how to make thickness even?

Thank you!
Best regards,

Comment: Before I'm wrecking my head what else could be the problem: Have you enabled _Even Thickness_ in the modifier settings?

Comment: Hello! Actually It was enabled Even Thickness option. but I have solved problem using Object mode - Object - Scale & Rotation. I don't know the principal, but now all the edge has same thickness even!

Comment: You mean you have applied the _Scale_ and _Rotation_ with `Ctrl`+`A`? That would have been my next question. Do understand what relations there are between scale and dimensions in Blender, see my answer on this question [Blender units and scale](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284940/blender-units-and-scale/284945#284945) or the answer to this question [Why do the measurements of this object seem erroneous?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/)